# Convert sprite image into CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an sprite image , I want to animate it , Below is the actual Animation.I coded by just copying code of some other website .It uses some Framework named motio 2.2 , But problem is it is not working in IOS.Below is the sample code and here is demo   https://codepen.io/adjmpw/pen/OmxVNO

```
var blue_cirlce_anim = jQuery('#' + BLUE_CIRCLE_ID);
            blue_cirlce_anim.css('cssText', 'display: block !important;');
            var motioBC = new Motio(blue_cirlce_anim[0], {
                fps: 60,
                frames: 97,
                vertical: true
            });
            motioBC.play();


https://codepen.io/adjmpw/pen/OmxVNO
```

I want to animate following images  , Using Css or Javascript or jquery

```
http://www.humanverify.net/captchalocker/img/blue-circle-anim.png

http://www.humanverify.net/captchalocker/img/blue-circle-loading-anim.png
```

What I tried So far

```
var imgHeight = 2844;
var numImgs = 100;
var cont = 0;
var img = $('#container').find('img');

var animation = setInterval( moveSprite,100);

function moveSprite(){
    img.css('margin-top', -1 * (cont*imgHeight));

    cont++;
    if(cont == numImgs){
        clearInterval(animation);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aTqGw/406/

Comment: Would something like this work instead? You can color it however you want: http://jsfiddle.net/aTqGw/407/

Comment: thank you for your comment , this just rotates image , It wont work for images like http://www.humanverify.net/captchalocker/img/blue-circle-anim.png